# How can I see what `Rack::Protection` is doing with Sinatra server?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra server in an AWS environment with a load balancer between the client and the server.

Unless I do something like:

```
disable: protection
```

it gives 'Forbidden' on a redirect. I don't want to always disable protection, and I should narrow the amount of disabled protection, so I would like to know what protection is forbidding my redirect.

I am expecting to see something like:

```
attack prevented by Rack::Protection::<Something>
```

I have:

```
enable: logging
```

and:

```
-e development
```

but can't get any feedback from `Rack::Protection` on why it is applying a rule.

I have tried this:

```
def self.log_rack_protection(namespace = nil, data = nil)
  puts "rack data: #{data.pretty_inspect}"
end
use Rack::Protection, instrumenter: log_rack_protection
```

but it doesn't seem to be called except on startup.

What do I need to do to get more feedback from `Rack::Protection` on what module is doing the blocking? Alternatively, is there some configuration we should be applying to the load balancer to stop this protection?

Comment: There was a similar issue in sidekiq with its Sinatra based web UI. Please see if [this thread](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1289#issuecomment-232330804) helps you. Basically, just ensure that you're passing appropriate headers from the reverse proxy (load balancer) to the rack.

Comment: Thanks @31piy .   Based on that reading and some experimentation disabling the 'remote_referrer' protection did the trick.

In Sinatra: `set :protection, :except => [:remote_referrer]`

Comment: Its great that you found a way on your own to solve this problem. To help future readers facing similar problem, you should add an answer describing what did you do, and then accept it.

Comment: Actually it seemed to be 
`set :protection, :except => [:json_csrf]`

Answer (score 1):

While I did not work out how to get better logging, I did work out that doing this:

```
set :protection, :except => [:json_csrf]
```

stopped the 'Forbidden' message on a client side redirect in the scenario described in the question.